# Multi-field vs. fielddata for querying and sorting

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have a simple "person" database using Elasticsearch 6 which looks basically like this:

```
id | firstName | lastName
-------------------------
1  | Tim       | Berners-Lee
2  | Linus     | Torvalds
3  | Noam      | Chomsky
```

I want to query by and sort by `lastName` (and/or by `firstName` - depending on user input).

Now I found 2 solutions which seems to work, but I'm not sure which one is "right" (or "better") and why:

1. Multi-field: `"type": "text", "fields": { "raw": { "type":  "keyword" } }`: I can query using `lastName` and sort using `lastName.raw`.
2. fielddata: `"type": "text", "fielddata": true`: Here I can query and sort using `lastName`.

But I'm not sure at all why I should choose one over the other and what implications this choice has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the below points will help you to decide based on you actual use case.

1. **Multi fields**

   Purpose of it - To store a single field with different analysers. As You have used `text` and `keyword`

   It doesn't have any special cache.
2. **Field data**

   Purpose of it - For faster access during aggregation/sorting. It loads all the data to field cache.
   Though you can achieve your need using this, it is expensive.

   1. Loading field data is expensive
   2. Once loaded it stays for the lifetime of the Lucene segments
   3. Since your field is text, it will occupy lots of heap space.

But you can control the number of terms loaded into memory using `fielddata_frequency_filter`

And you do sort on `text` field. And the recommendation from the document is

> Instead, you should have a text field for full text searches, and an unanalyzed keyword field with doc_values enabled for aggregations

So, you need to choose based on data size, data access patterns, cost for the servers in case if you have more data and planning to use `field data`

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! If I understood correctly: Multi-field is the recommendation, it uses much less system memory, but is slower? I couldn't see any performance difference from my small tests, but the database has less than 10000 entries - and I don't expect it to grow much more.

Comment: 10K do not show much difference but 10M would show that. As it won't grow much, you can use multi-field. How often you update them?

Comment: Maybe 5 updates and 5 inserts per day. There's not much going on in this database.